# TypeError: 'float' object not callable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm pretty new to coding so this may be a silly problem but when I try to run my programme I get the error mentioned in the title.
The bit of code which seems to be the problem is this:

```
def branch(replicas):
    ER = d * 0.5 * w
    N0 = len(replicas)
    newReplicas = []   ##### Error on this line 

    for j in range( len(replicas) ):

        replica = replicas[j]

        r2 = 0

        for x in replica:

            r2 += x * x

            V = 0.5 * mass * w**2 * r2

            W = exp(-(V - ER) / rootT)

            mn = int(W + random.uniform(0,1))

            if mn >= 3:

                newReplicas.append( replica )

                newReplicas.append( replica )

                newReplicas.append( replica )

            elif mn == 2:    

                newReplicas.append( replica )

                newReplicas.append( replica )

            elif mn == 1:

                newReplicas.append( replica )

    replicas = newReplicas
    N1 = len(replicas)
    ER = ER + ((hbar/deltaT)(1-(N1/N0)))
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your last line supposed to do? You have a close paren followed by an open paren.

Comment: The last line is supposed to modify a variable ER which I defined in a line before the block that you can see here. Thanks for pointing that out, I've fixed it and no longer get the error!

Comment: I would hazard to guess that a multiplication goes there, between the closed and open parenthesis. Otherwise, that would be where the TypeError is generated.

Comment: There are many variables that defined in the global context: d, w, mass.  Not the problem, but not good practice either.

Comment: Those variables are all input values which I need to use in various parts of the programme. What is bad about defining things in the global context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem lies here

```
ER = ER + ((hbar/deltaT)(1-(N1/N0)))
```

I think what you're after is this

```
ER = ER + ((hbar/deltaT)*(1-(N1/N0)))
```

What Python thinks you want is to call a object of the value returned by evaluating

```
hbar/deltaT
```

So if

```
hbar = 2.0
deltaT = 1.0
```

then it thinks your trying to call the float object it creates, as in this case it would be a float object of the value 2.0, with the parameter of the result of evaluating

```
1-(N1/N0)
```

Since float objects are not callable, this doesn't work, and throws and exception.

Essentially you can fix this by putting the multiplication operator between

```
(hbar/deltaT)
```

and

```
(1-(N1/N0))
```

ending up with

```
((hbar/deltaT)*(1-(N1/N0)))
```

Which is what I think you're trying to do.  Unless you didn't want to do multiplication